# Select foreach loop range by number

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, foreach

I want to make a foreach with 0-25 range of numbers which are inside tables. So if the database `number_exist` value of `020` does exist in the database, instead of creating a radio box with a label of numbers in the foreach loop, just remove the radio-box and the number label and make the background to black or any color so it should be disabled or unavailable, how should i do it? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

================

Database Name: testing

Table Name: codetest

which have a data of

```
====================
||id||number_exist||
||==||============||
|| 1||    020     ||
====================
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

define('DB_NAME', 'testing');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

function sql_connect() {
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) 
    or die ("Could not connect to server ... \n" . mysql_error ());
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) 
    or die ("Could not connect to database ... \n" . mysql_error ());
}

<table border="1" style="margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;text-align:center;"><tr>

<?php 
foreach (range(0, 25) as $number) {
$number=sprintf('%03d', $number);

sql_connect();
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM codetest");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$exist=$row['number_exist'];

if ($number==$exist) {
$labelme="NA";
} else {
$labelme="<input type='radio' name='lot' value='".$number."' id='".$number."' class='rad'>
<label for='".$number."'>".$number."</label>";
}
}
echo "<td>";
echo $labelme;
echo "</td>";
}
?>

</tr></table>
```

Comment: what is the problem you're having?

Comment: Query the database, use a conditional statement to compare against the the returned value.

Comment: Is `number_exist` a VARCHAR or INT, or other? Using a `foreach` may require you to use `IN` or `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: Hi, i was having a hard time comparing the value of the existed value in the database and the foreach range value, if the foreach range value of 020 is existing in the database, then the foreach range value of 020 must not echo radio button and label, instead echo that the background color will change to black or anything.. thanks

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi sir, the number_exist is a varchar, because ill be using other methods on that later on, i just want to foreach the 0-20 and if the existing value in the database is 020 then the foreach 020 must be background black and doesnt have any radio buttons or label..

Comment: @Ohgodwhy can you help me code for it sir, since im new at php... thank you.. actually im trying my best to code it since last week, but cant get a hold of it.. thanks

Comment: Have you written any code to query the database yet? Please post that if so.

Comment: @ialarmedalien sir i updated the code above, please kindly take a look at it, the query above seemed to put "NA" instead of "radio box and label of number" in the number "020" but the thing is, if i put two numbers in the database that is the "020" and the "021" the echo puts only "NA" on number "021" instead of both "020" and "021".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an if-else statement inside your foreach. If `$number` is *020* *echo* that it's unavailable else *echo* the radiobutton.

Comment: sir i updated the code above, please kindly take a look at it, the query above seemed to put "NA" instead of "radio box and label of number" in the number "020" but the thing is, if i put two numbers in the database that is the "020" and the "021" the echo puts only "NA" on number "021" instead of both "020" and "021".

Comment: After you echo "NA", you need to break out of the while loop, otherwise, it'll keep going to the next number. Also, try refactoring your code. Right now, the same query is called everytime the foreach runs, when it really only needs to be called once at the beginning.

Comment: thanks for the response sir, but how should i do it sir? since im just new to php .. thank you sir

Comment: After $labelme="NA"; add break;

Comment: i did sir, but i inserted now two which is the "020" and the "021", but the only "NA" was the "020" the "021" isn't "NA", the number "021" is still there, though it's in the number_exist

Comment: sir, thank you, i accidentally putted 2 breaks on both of my $label, thank you so much....